# Install Cabocha on windows 10 with anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, anaconda

I am trying to install cabocha on my windows 10 pc but have had little luck in doing so. 
I have mecab successfully install and working with python and anaconda.

Could someone please point me into the right direction or give step by step instructions to install this. 
I have tried this one
https://github.com/kenkov/cabocha
And I tried this one.
https://qiita.com/mima_ita/items/161cd869648edb30627b

Any help on this would be appreciated.

I am using

## Name                    Version                   Build  Channel

anaconda                  5.2.0                    py36_3

On windows 10

Thank you

Comment: what is the error??

Comment: The windows installation does not come back with an error, but when I try to use it in python, it say cabocha not a modual